# Saving a CKRecordID to CloudKit

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit, ckrecord, ckreference

I have a `CKRecordID` that I need to save to CloudKit as a reference. However when I try to save it, I get the following Error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'CKRecordID?' to expected argument type 'CKRecordValue?'

Declaration of currentlySelectedUser:

```
var currentlySelectedUser: CKRecordID?
```

Retrieval of currentlySelectedUser in another CKQuery:

```
self.currentlySelectedUser = record.creatorUserRecordID
```

Saving of currentlySelectedUser:

```
myRecord.setObject(currentlySelectedUser, forKey: "toUser")
```

The error occurs at the 3rd line of code.

How do I save this `CKRecordID` as a reference in another CloudKit record?

Comment: Update your question with the relevant code and point out the exact line causing the error.

Comment: @rmaddy i have updated the question with the relevant lines of code

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to add a `CKRecordID` which is not a data type supported by `CKRecord`. As the error says, it doesn't conform to the `CKRecordValue` protocol.

Create a `CKReference` and add it like this:

```
myRecord["toUser"] = CKReference(recordID: currentlySelectedUser!, action: .None)
```